# Is there a way to get the i-numbered item of a combobox?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a combobox in a userform. I want to get the first and last value of it's items. I can of course loop through the items and get them in that way, but that isn't really efficient.

Is there a way to do something like combobox.row(2) for the third item?

Comment: First could be ```Me.ComboBox1.List(0)``` and last ```Me.ComboBox1.List(Me.ComboBox1.ListCount - 1)```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes:

```
Me.ComboBox1.List(2)
```

for example. You can also specify a column number too, if the source has more than one column.